# How should I manage my code of if else condition to something else?

Tags: javascript, loops

I've three methods for eg.:

```
function method1(){
   console.log('method1');
}
function method2(){
   console.log('method2');
}
function method3(){
   console.log('method3');
}
```

Now I'm going to apply these methods within the if else condition like below:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
   //for first 4 iteration apply method1:
   if(i<4){
      method1();
   }
   //next fifth iteration apply method2:
   else if(i==4){
      method2();
   }
   //next 3 iteration apply method3: 
   else if(i>4 && i<8){
      method3();
   }
   //next ninth iteration apply method2:
   else if(i==8){
      method2();
   }
   //next 3 iteration apply method1:
   else if(i>8 && i<12){
      method1();
   }
   ...........
}
```

Like this I've to make iteration upto 100 or say if it was even longer, then the process of coding would be so longer and may be irritating .

Thus, I thought there might be an easier way to solve this problem.

To make this concept even more clearer what I wanted to do, I'm presenting you a graph from which solution for this question would be easy to follow:

[image]

---

## you can skip to read the following:

<sup>While preparing for the graph of this question, the following concept came into my mind:</sup>

**From the graph above,**

- You may know first 4 iterations have the method1.
- Next 5th(4), 9th(8), 13th(12), 17th(16), 21st(20), 25th(24),
  29th(28), and so on iterations have method2.
- The next iterations from method2 and lower than following method2
  iteration have method3.
- And all other iterations have method1.

---

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
   //find the series 5th, 9th, 13th, and so on and apply method2:
   if( i == 5 + 4  * n){
      method2();
   }

   //find the series between 9th and 5th and so on and apply method3:
   else if( i > ( 5 + 4 * n ) && i < ( 5 + 4 * n - 1) ){
      method3();
   }

   //for other iterations apply method 1:
   else{
      method1();
   }
}//end for loop
```

---

So, this is almost might be after the solution but still confusing to iterate to n. Suppose if I place n to for loop like `for(var i=0,n=0;i<100;i++)` then it would iterate like if i is 5 then n is 5 and after then 5+4*5 = 25 and never would get the match.

```
for(var i=0,n=0; i<100; i++){
   if(i%4==0){
   n=-1;
}
//now i becomes equal when i is 5 then n is -1 at 4th i so 0 at 5th i and 5+4*0 = 5.... matched
//now check for next 9th i equals n: i is 9 then n is -1 at 8th i so 0 at 9th i and 5+4*0=5... not matched as this time it should be 1 for n
```

Ummm, still confusing to solve this problem as n's value should be -1 at 4th i and 0 at 8th i and 1 at 12th i and so on.....

And still unsure about my else if condition what will work or not.
So, Please help me to solve this problem.

You may go your own way as easier as you can.

Comment: I don't have a whole lot of time to post a full answer but consider creating a set of dynamic cases rendered at the beginning of each iteration that are resolved with a `switch, case` clause. It should provide a clean and functional solution to your issue.

Comment: This is an interesting design pattern, but I'm slightly confused: To which real-world situation is this pattern being applied?

Comment: This is really a 'math' problem in my opinion.  Sit down, and take your time to truly understand the pattern of which method should be used when.  Write out a formula.  Break into cases only when absolutely necessary.  You are on the right track with this n business, but i don't think your formula is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your program follows this pattern

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    if (i % 4 === 0 && i) {
        method2();             // Current index is divisible by 4
    } else if (i % 8 < 4) {
        method1();             // Current index is within 0-3, 8-11, ...
    } else {
        method3();             // Current index is within 5-7, 13-15, ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The op said `for first 4 iteration apply method1`, your code breaks when i is 0.

Comment: it works almost as good as mine, but 0 % 4 = 0, so, your answer will call method2 when it should call method1 in that condition. but if you fix this, your answer is correct ;D

Comment: @Buzinas Actually, I am not very sure. As per the pattern, it should call `method2` only, anyway I fixed it :)

Comment: @xdazz Please check now, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

In these conditions here is what I would do:

I would go to good old excel, in 1 column is the iterator i, in the other is the methods I would like to run.

Then I would write a macro to auto generate the code to copy/ paste it. It will take time, but if this is something reusable, your excel becomes your design and documentation.

Comment: can you provide your answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the code in the below pattern, then fix the your math problem.

```
var foo = {
  method1: function(){
    console.log('method1');
  },
  method2: function(){
    console.log('method2');
  },
  method3: function(){
    console.log('method3');
  }
}

var bar = function (num) {
  // put your formular here
  return num;
}

for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  foo['method'+bar(i)]();
}
```

Comment: I liked your method very much. But you are saying to put the formula within the bar function. Can you show me a demo?

Comment: Since you've liked his answer more than the others, I've edited it to put the Math formula inside it. Now, we only need to wait for it getting approved =)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
        method2();
    }
    else if (parseInt(i / 4) % 2 == 0) {
        method1();
    }
    else {
        method3();
    }
}
```

Take a look at this **[fiddle example I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/zdzy6/)**!

Comment: Quiz: Compare this answer with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22853042/1903116) and find the differences ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your graph shows that only initially method1 executes 4 times (between 0 to 3). After that there is a patterns of method3 and method1 executing 3 times each but separated by method2 (every 4 time). If this is the case until the end of the series, then the following code would work -

```
if (nCtr < 4) {
   method1();
} else if ((nCtr % 4) == 0) {
    method2();
} else if (((nCtr / 4) % 2) == 0) {   // nCtr divided by 4 produces even number
    Method1();
} else {                              // nCtr divided by 4 produces odd number
    Method3();
}
```